# ListPreference with a max number of selectable options

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to have an element in my preference menu that does the following:

- Show a list of options.
- Many are selectable
- Maximum amount of options to be chosen 2.

Possibilities I thought of:

1. Doing a separated `PreferenceScreen` and showing options as `checkBoxes`, but I don't know where to place the logic of max 2 options.
2. Extending `DialogPreference` and doing it by hand.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending `DialogPreference` would get you the closest in terms of look-and-feel; the `Preference` classes are fairly unflexible and un-extendable in my experience.

I can't remember too much about `PreferenceScreen`, but I imagine it's similar.

In an app I worked on, we ended up using separate activities, launched via `Intent` from a `Preference` item onClick.  This allowed us to easily develop preference screens that require validation logic a bit more complex than the usual.

Comment: This is what I did:
 * Extend from DialogPreference.
 * On onCreateDialogView I create a layout with different checkboxes.
 * My values are loaded in a String separated by a token.
 * Created a class that coverts from String to int[] and vice versa.
 ** This class uses a HashSet and has a maxSize.

It's kind of a hack but it works :)
Thanks Christopher.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the logic of maximum two options in a [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

So you just listen to all the preferences as they change and update them if an invalid combination is selected.

So your code would be something like the following:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {
    //Code to calcuate how many are selected
    int code = numberSelected();

    if (count > 2) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key,false).commit();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Can't select more than two!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If you create your own [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) that implements `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` you can enable the listener to be listening only when required doing something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    //Register the listener
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```